# Parse the string to take the date before putting each variable into datetime object

Tags: c#, string, date, parsing, datetime

I get this warning when I try to execute the attaching code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace prueb2 {
   public partial class Acusado: Form {
       public Acusado() {
           InitializeComponent();
       }

       private void Acusado_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
           listView1.Items.Clear();
           List < ACUSADOcLAS > listaAcusado;

           try {
               listaAcusado = BD.GetAcusado();
               if (listaAcusado.Count > 0) {
                   ACUSADOcLAS acusado;
                   for (int i = 0; i < listaAcusado.Count; i++) {
                       acusado = listaAcusado[i];
                       listView1.Items[i].SubItems.Add(acusado.NumeroSeguroSocial.ToString());
                       listView1.Items[i].SubItems.Add(acusado.NombreAcusado);
                       listView1.Items[i].SubItems.Add(acusado.ApellidoPaternoAcusado);
                       listView1.Items[i].SubItems.Add(acusado.ApellidoMaternoAcusado);
                       listView1.Items[i].SubItems.Add(acusado.FechaNacimientoAcusado.ToString());

                       listView1.Items[i].SubItems.Add(acusado.GeneroAcusado);
                       listView1.Items[i].SubItems.Add(acusado.DireccionAcusado);
                       listView1.Items[i].SubItems.Add(acusado.NivelMaximoEstudiosAcusado);
                       listView1.Items[i].SubItems.Add(acusado.EtnicidadAcusado);
                       listView1.Items[i].SubItems.Add(acusado.ReligionAcusado);
                   }
               } else {
                   MessageBox.Show("No hay acusados", "Alerta");
               }
           } catch (Exception ex) {
               MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, ex.GetType().ToString());
           }
       }

       private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
           BD.AddAcusado(int.Parse(txtNumSeg.Text), txtNombreA.Text, txtApPat.Text, txtApMat.Text, DateTime.Parse(dateTimeFecha.Text), comboGenero.Text, txtDireccion.Text, comboEstudios.Text, txtEtnicidad.Text, txtReligion.Text);
           txtNumSeg.Text = "";
           txtNombreA.Text = "";
           txtApPat.Text = "";
           txtApMat.Text = "";
           dateTimeFecha.Text = "";
           comboGenero.Text = "";
           txtDireccion.Text = "";
           comboEstudios.Text = "";
           txtEtnicidad.Text = "";
           txtReligion.Text = "";
           this.Acusado_Load(this, null);
       }

   }
}
```

Can you help me please?

Comment: How does your `DateTime` format looks like?

Comment: You are clearing the date each time the button is clicked : dateTimeFecha.Text = "";  Make sure the textbox contains a date before you click the button

Answer (score 0):

You are probably getting exception because of the invalid date string. You need to validate it first.

Try this:

```
DateTime tempDateTimeFecha;
bool isValid = DateTime.TryParse(dateTimeFecha.Text, out tempDateTimeFecha);
```

Now if `isValid == true` you can pass  `tempDateTimeFecha` as argument to the`BD.AddAcusado()` method.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue trying to parse the Date column of my datagridview. The following procedure helped me resolve it:
      I checked my loop body and decreased the maximum number for loop termination by 1.

```
    int days = 0;
    Datetime d;
    for (int i = 1; i < pastedCells -1; i++){ 
            d = Convert.ToDateTime(dgv_Copy.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);
            days = DateTime.DaysInMonth(d.Year, d.Month);
            Console.WriteLine(days + "\t" + d);
       }
    //result:
    //31    2002-05-31 0:00
    //30    2002-11-30 0:00
    //31    2003-05-31 0:00
    //30    2003-06-30 0:00
    //31    2003-10-31 0:00
    //30    2003-11-30 0:00
    //29    2004-02-29 0:00
    //31    2004-10-31 0:00
```

Pls Note: Parsing Dates depend on the format (check this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/parsing-datetime for more info. MORE IMPORTANTLY, if your loop body tries to pass a **null** or **empty**, then it will definitely pop up error.

Also, remember to catch the exception but not after checking for coding error.